# Problems loading package in R

Tags: r

When I try to load fPortfolio, the following error message occures. Do someone knows how to solve this?

```
> library("fPortfolio")

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fPortfolio’ in loadNamespace(i c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘XML’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly install `XML` package:

```
  install.packages("XML")
```

After that, try again.